# Github actions branch deployment rules

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

I would like to trigger deployment if the any commit is pushed to the branch named release/1.0 or release/2.0 and so on with the same structure.
I am doing it by using the following rule

```
if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/release/*/*' }}
```

The above rule does not work and the run is ignored during the build i.e the if block does not satisfy.

Any ideas how I can make changes to the rule for it to run?

Answer (score 0):

Using `release/**` fixed my issue